# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to get a data parsing script up and running. It works as far as the data manipulation is concerned. What I'm trying to do is set this up so I can enter multiple user defined CSV's with a single command.

e.g.

```
> python script.py One.csv Two.csv Three.csv
```

If you have any advice on how to automate the naming of the output CSV so that if `input = test.csv`, `output = test1.csv`, I'd appreciate that as well.

Getting

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

for the line

```
for line in csv.reader(open(args.infile)):
```

My code:

```
import csv
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
res = []

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#parser.add_argument("infile", nargs="*", type=str)
#args = parser.parse_args()

parser.add_argument ("infile", metavar="CSV", nargs="+", type=str, help="data file") 
args = parser.parse_args()


with open("out.csv","wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f) 
    for line in csv.reader(open(args.infile)): 
        for item in line[2:]:

            #to skip empty cells
            if not item.strip():
                continue

            item = item.split(":")
            item[1] = item[1].rstrip("%")

            print([line[1]+item[0],item[1]])
            res.append([line[1]+item[0],item[1]])
            output.writerow([line[1]+item[0],item[1].rstrip("%")])
```

I don't really understand what is going on with the error. Can someone explain this in layman's terms?

Bear in mind I am new to programming/python as a whole and am basically learning alone, so if possible could you explain what is going wrong/how to fix it so I can note it for future reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`args.infile` is a *list* of filenames, not one filename. Loop over it:

```
for filename in args.infile:
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    with open("{}1{}".format(base, ext), "wb") as outf, open(filename, 'rb') as inf:
        output = csv.writer(outf) 
        for line in csv.reader(inf):
```

Here I used `os.path.splitext()` to split extension and base filename so you can generate a new output filename adding `1` to the base.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify an `nargs` argument to `.add_argument`, the argument will always be returned as a list.

Assuming you want to deal with all of the files specified, loop through that list:

```
for filename in args.infile:
    for line in csv.reader(open(filename)): 
        for item in line[2:]:

            #to skip empty cells
[...]
```

Or if you really just want to be able to specify a single file; just get rid of `nargs="+"`.