# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found: how to create a loop

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script that will add a folder and all of its contents to a zip file using both `zipfile` and `os`.

```
z = ZipFile("mynewfile.zip", "w")
z.write(os.walk(directory))
z.printdir()
z.close()
```

Unfortunatly I've found that this is considered a list when using `os.walk`, which causes the error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found: how to create a loop
```

Looking around at this error, I think I need a loop to cycle through each item in the list. My problem is that I can't figure out how to translate previous answers for my specific needs. 
e.g [TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580270/typeerror-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer-list-found)

I have also tried

```
for root dirs files in os.walk(directory)
    z.write(files)
```

which also causes the same error to occur.

However using

```
for root dirs files in os.walk(directory)
    z.write(root)
```

displays all the folders within the directory, but no files. I'm not sure why this does not count as a list.

I assume I need to somehow combine these 2 ideas, any help doing so would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: if `files` is a list, then why not just have a second (inner) for loop which iterates over all elements of that list? (Also none of the examples you posted have actually valid syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do it. Since files is a list. You simply iterate over that list and write the filenames to the zipfile. In the code below I'm also using the context manager `with` with that I don't need to close the file manually, because it does that for me.

```
from zipfile import Zipfile

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        with Zipfile('new_zip.zip', 'w') as z:
            z.write(f)
```